# Paste from Gnome clipboard, but replace newlines with spaces

Tags: linux, gnome, clipboard

I sometimes copy text from a PDF to another file and am annoyed when all the newlines are copied over as well. Is there someway to create a custom keyboard shortcut that intercepts what I'm pasting and lets me run a script modifying the contents before they're pasted? Do I have to use a clipboard manager to accomplish this? Alternatively, should I be trying to do this text transformation on ingestion of text instead?